# eWay Payment Processor error 9001 on contribution - help please

Tags: wordpress, payment-processor, eway

eWay Payment Processor error 9001 on Contact's Contribution page.

Setup new eWay account works fine with Xero, however, with CiviCrm (4.7.10) when used with a Contact's Contribution page I get a "9001 error. Connection to payment gateway failed - no data found". Have tried the delivered eWay processor and also Chris Chincilla's V1.2 and I get the same behaviour.

Have checked the setup many times and it is correct. Have deleted the payment processor and then re-added it. No change.

Can anybody help me or point me in he right direction please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed. My hosting company migrated my site to another server which could communicate with eWay and it is now working.

Comment: ideally you would 'accept' your own answer and help close this off